# Sorting Data at the runtime in Oracle PL/SQL using Associative array

Tags: oracle, sorting, plsql, associative-array

I am trying to sort a data from runtime query and no way I can do that without use of a collection. Essentially, I have 2 columns in Service table - SERVICE_ID, SERVICE_NAME. I have created an Associative array in a package so that I can use it in my procedure.

```
TYPE g_vc_arr IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

In my pl/sql block I am creating a variable like below:

```
service_list my_pkg.g_vc_arr;
```

I am assigning the SERVICE_ID and SERVICE_NAME to this variable like below:

```
LOOP
  service_list(services.SERVICE_ID) := services.SERVICE_NAME;
END LOOP;
```

Now, I am using this to sort the name column like below snippet. I am able to print the name but in this process, I am losing the ID.

```
for query_result_row in (SELECT * from table(service_list) order by 1) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(query_result_row.COLUMN_VALUE);
end loop;
```

I need both ID and NAME to process further. How can I get both?

Comment: Just defined a collection of integer index by varchar2 and use names as a key for it, then just use iterators (or my old iterators: http://orasql.org/2017/10/02/plsql-functions-iterate-and-keys-for-associative-arrays/

Comment: In this case your collection will be sorted already by keys

Comment: Without any sql

Comment: Post your source for  getting service.service_name for your assignment statement. If `select`ing from a table or having built a cursor you may not need to loop nor the sort.

Comment: Seems like the question is not about sorting despite the title. I think it's about how to display the array index as a column when treating a PL/SQL associative array as a relational table. Or is it really just about sorting?

Comment: Essentially, I am trying to get the data sorted, sorting is concern for me. I can always pull the data without sorting, but that will not solve the purpose. I can't sort the data while inserting the data into the associative array.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you don't need to sort it as it is already held in the order you defined it:

```
create or replace package demo
as
    type currency_tt is table of varchar2(3) index by pls_integer;

    currencies demo.currency_tt :=
        demo.currency_tt
        ( 1 => 'USD'
        , 2 => 'GBP'
        , 3 => 'EUR' );
end demo;
```

```
begin
    for r in (
        select * from table(demo.currencies)
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.column_value);
    end loop;
end;
```

Output:

```
USD
GBP
EUR
```

But you don't need SQL, as you can iterate over an associative array procedurally:

```
declare
    i pls_integer := demo.currencies.first;
begin
    while i is not null loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i||' '||demo.currencies(i));
        i := demo.currencies.next(i);
    end loop;
end;
```

Or from 21c you can loop more conveniently like this:

```
begin
    for id, ccy in pairs of demo.currencies loop
        dbms_output.put_line(id || ' '|| ccy);
    end loop;
end;
```

```
1 USD
2 GBP
3 EUR
```

Comment: Thank you! However, data is not sorted.. I need data in sorted for Currency in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my approach a bit to solve this issue. I created a package with 2 column TYPE as record and an associative array of the record type:

```
create or replace package my_pkg is 
TYPE g_rec_type IS RECORD (ID  NUMBER, name VARCHAR2(4000));
TYPE g_rec_arr IS TABLE OF g_rec_type INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
end my_pkg;
```

In my actual PL/sqL block I created couple of variables:

```
 i NUMBER := 0;
 service_list MY_PKG.g_rec_arr;
```

Then I created a loop to assign the values to array:

```
LOOP
    service_list(i).ID := services.SERVICE_ID;
    service_list(i).NAME := services.SUMMARY;
    i := i+1;
END LOOP;
```

Further to sort the value I used following:

```
FOR query_result_row in (SELECT ID, NAME from table(service_list) order by NAME) LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line('ID is =>' || query_result_row.ID|| ' Name is =>' || query_result_row.NAME);
END LOOP;
```

And it worked as expected.